# Java: regenerate static attribute after unit testing

Tags: java, static, junit, attributes

I am writing a unit test that is modifying a static attribute.  Unfortunately, this is causing another unit test to fail when it shouldn't. The attribute is also final (the attribute is an object that holds values so by modifying it, I mean adding/removing values).

Currently I set the object (edit: Not object. variable that is being tested) to null in the tearDown() method and initialize it in the setUp() method, but this isn't resetting the attribute.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't set an *object* to null - only a variable. Which means we don't really know what your code looks like. Can you give an example of the production code and sample tests?

Answer (score 0):

In your @After method consider resetting the static field using [ReflectionTestUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)

Comment: if you want to keep the test value for the whole of the test then you could use @AfterClass which will then only update after the whole of the test class has completed

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to question why you have a static field and work out how to get rid of it. Look at things like Dependency Inject to remove this dependency on a static value.